# Distinguish Event Receiver Firing From Web UI or From Code

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers, object-model

Think of some event receiver methods like ItemAdded, ItemDeleted etc.

How can I detect in my event receiver code if the item adding/deleting is being triggered from the web UI or from the object model / custom code?

Comment: I don't think you can... maybe someone can prove me wrong.